# Google analytics event tracking, retrieve results

Tags: events, google-analytics

I'm trying to use google event tracking to track some events on buttons on my magento site. Everything seems to be working fine because I don't get errors on the pages where the tracking code is located but I don't know how to retrieve the data captured through this code on google analytics.

Does google analytics has a dedicated section for this kind of event tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Pablo, if everything is working fine you will be able to see event statistics in section Reporting -> Behaviour -> Events